# Why does my page start higher in Safari and firefox than in Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser

I'm coding www.rootologyhealth.com and I cannot figure out why the Nav Bar on the homepage starts so high up in Safari and Firefox but looks perfect in chrome. I've done all the work I can to try to diagnose the problem. I'm certain its a stylesheet issue, but the styles I'm using are relatively simple and shouldn't be causing this problem.

Comment: it seems to me identical fine in all browsers on Mac OS, what version of browsers do you use and what OS?

Comment: Are you using an older version of html5boilerplate? I had a similar issue not too long ago involving the clearfix rules they included. You may want to try a different clearfix or google around for "htlm5boilerplate extra spacing firefox top" or something similar

Comment: Check out http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's broken in Chrome 21 and fine in Firefox 14 on Windows 7.

When messing around with the developer tools in Chrome, if you take `div#top-menu` out of `div.container`, it no longer floats up above the viewable portion of the browser.  You'll be left with a spacing issue between that and the large advert, but that should be simpler to deal with.

Comment: Thanks Cypher - that worked, now I need to figure out how to get around Safari ignoring the Height css variable :) Thanks for the help -you rock.